# Support for multi tenancy in SpringBoot 3 native image

Tags: spring-boot, multi-tenant, graalvm, graalvm-native-image

I am building a Java spring boot microservice which is configured with single database multi schema strategy. Now I am creating native image using the native profile in pom.xml using graalvm.

Can someone confirm if multi tenancy is supported or not when creating native image ?

I am getting

```
UnsatisfiedDependencyException: error creating bean with name 'myAppServiceImpl' : Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'personRespository': Error creating bean name 'personRespository': Not a managed type: c.e.services.myappservice.identity.PersonEntity

Caused by: BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'personRespository': Not a managed type...
```

Answer (score 0):

I could find the fix in internet https://github.com/DigitalMediageek/aot-database-issue

For extra resolution for multitenancy you can follow the changes here : [Issue of "IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: MyEntity" for native image using spring boot 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78206016/issue-of-illegalargumentexception-not-a-managed-type-myentity-for-native-ima/78207737#78207737)